Create a CSV file by adding double quotes to the column with multiple commas in Power Flow
I have built a power flow which gets a CSV file daily in the service account and the power flow takes it and creates a file in the SharePoint folder. I face an issue when the pipeline I have built on ADF takes this file from SharePoint and pushes it to the SQL table. It considers the commas in the value as separators and creates a new column. I am trying to achieve where as soon as I receive the file, the power flow itself can add double quotes to the appropriate text columns so this can be automated.



instance.tt
metric
value
string_value




4 - Low
Please fee
0
IT staff are the best when servicing UM staff, people


4 - Low
How satisfa
5
It was good, promptly problem was solved. very efficiency


4 - Low
Please fee
0
The Technical Support line, is not helpful




I have a CSV file which has a column with multiple commas within the data. As you can see in the string_value field. It has commas in multiple rows. When I push this CSV to the SQL Server table, SQL creates a new column for the data after the comma. And as I have already setup a flow which takes the CSV from the email and pushing it to the folder from where the pipeline runs, I wanted to insert some steps within the flow which can edit that column in the CSV and add double quotes because SQL considers the field with double quotes as one and I can get that entire text with comma in one cell.

What does the raw CSV file look like? If it were encoded properly then it should already have quotes around the string_value. i.e.: for minimal quoting the first data line should be 4 - Low,Please fee,0,"IT staff are the best when servicing UM staff, people", or if the file was using full quoting it should be "4 - Low","Please fee","0","IT staff are the best when servicing UM staff, people". If it's not encoded with either of these two forms then it's not a correctly encoded CSV file and you should encourage the data provider to fix their problems.

Yes it is full quoting that is all the fields are within the double quotes
